# Not sure how to normalize counts by version after using groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is the command I'm using:

```
data.groupby('version')['rating'].value_counts().sort_index()
```

And I'm left with:

```
version  rating
v1       0.0        51791
         1.0        11982
         2.0         1679
         3.0         1539
         4.0         6497
         4.5            1
         5.0       114382
v2       0.0        47396
         1.0         3591
         2.0          607
         3.0         1384
         4.0        10285
         5.0       159273
Name: rating, dtype: int64
```

Here are the overall value_counts() for each version:

```
version
v1    187871
v2    222536
Name: rating, dtype: int64
```

What I would like to do is take the counts for each these ratings count is normalize them based on the overall counts for each version.

I'm not sure of any elegant way to do this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just pass `True` to `normalize`

```
data.groupby('version')['rating'].value_counts(normalize=True).sort_index()
```

Comment: oh my god, why haven't I ever looked at the `value_counts` documentation. This is great, thanks for sharing.